# I'm having issues with adding a paused function to my code, can I have some assistance?

Tags: python, pygame

With my code I'm having trouble adding a pause function to my python game, I've tried different things and adjusting it a bit and it just made it worse and it still doesn't work, so can I please have some assistance with fixing it? If you find other issues with the code it can you please inform me as well?

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)

bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)

block_color =  (53, 115, 255)

car_width = 73

pause = False

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height ))
pygame.display.set_caption('The Racecar Derby')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def carImg():
    pygame.image.load('racecar.png')

carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')

def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render('Dodged: '+str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0, 0))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, block_color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()



def crash():
    message_display('You Crashed')

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "play":
                game_loop()
            elif action == "quit":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def unpause():
    global pause
    pause = False
    

def paused():
    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Continue",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,unpause)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,"quit")


def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Racecar Derby", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("GO!!!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,"quit")


        



        
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
        


def game_loop():
    global pause

    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 4
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100


    dodged = 0
    

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    pause = True
                    paused()


            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0
    
        x += x_change
        gameDisplay.fill(white)

        # things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color)
        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, block_color)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        car(x, y)
        things_dodged(dodged)

        if x > display_width - car_width or x < 0:
            crash()
        if thing_starty > display_height:
                  thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
                  thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
                  dodged += 1
                  thing_speed += 1
                  thing_width += (dodged * 1.2)


        if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
            print('y crossover')

            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x+car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx+thing_width:
                print('x crossover')
                crash()

        
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a global pause variable to implement this. A simpiler solution is to call your pause function when the key is pressed

```
if event.key == pygame.K_p:
      paused()
```

Then within in your pause function have a loop running until a condition is met. in the example below I have a version of your pause function loop with local pause variable until an event key is pressed.

```
def paused():
    paused = True
    
    while paused:
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                paused = False  # This will break the paused loop
                

        # This code below will run until event.key is pressed
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Continue",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,unpause)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,"quit")
```

For your implementation you don't necessarily need to use the event key that I used. The take away is the implementation of the local boolean switch (paused variable.

Hope this helped!